# PHP Short Term Password Memory

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, password-protection

I am writing a form builder and processing plugin for WordPress. In order to help combat spam registrations, I have chosen to have the user input all their information on the main registration page. Then upon submission, they will go to a confirmation page to review their information before they are actually registered and put into the database.

My question is, what is the most secure way to store the user's password server-side for the short time the user reviews their information prior to confirming  and completing the registration process.

Currently I put all the user's data into a session variables, then process the variables upon successful registration. Is it safe to keep the password in the session, or should I create a hidden form field on the page to store the password?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using hidden fields is probably the worst option you could choose besides visually displaying it on the page.

There's nothing wrong with session variables, and if you wanted to go a step further you could say that if you don't need the password after it's been checked/validated, hash it then store the hash in the session instead of the plaintext password. If you store it as a hash, and it only persists (in an already *relatively* secure manner) for a minute or so until the customer completes your UX process, then you **unset it again** after you've sent it to your database, there's no problem.

Bare in mind that session variables live on the server, not the client, so they're about as safe as any other information you're protecting in your system. This is opposed to if you were storing the password in a hidden field in your HTML, which is client side and is vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll store the password hashed in a session variable.